# What are the hidden combos in Oh! Edo Towns?

Tags: ios, oh-edo-towns

I have been playing [Oh! Edo Towns](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id474177077) (the new Kairosoft game for iOS), and have created all the combos currently available to me. The game mentions needing to create "hidden" combos - what are these, and what buildings do they use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a translated document of the combo moves...

[Oh Edo Combo Guide](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?hl=en_US&key=0ApJcOk7MQHDMdHMyZ0RQekxOVjJSYTRoYnBReXlnNVE&toomany=true#gid=0)

```
Combo Name  Facility    Facility    Facility    Yield   Price   Total Cost      

    Snack   Udon Shop   Soba Shop   Stew Cart   15％     10％     240G    
    Flower  Dumpling S. Cherry Tree Pond        18％     5％      460G    
    Sweets  Bun Shop    Bean Soup   Dumpling Sh 15％     10％     210G    
    Plum    Pub         Rice Shop   Plum Tree   20％     10％     350G    
   Kamakura Daibutsu    Bun Shop    Hydrangeas  24％     16％     890G    
    Lunch   Rice Shop   Tempura Sh. Greengrocer 20％     8％      340G    
    Noodle  Udon Shop   Soba Shop   Tempura Sh. 10％     5％      300G    
    Refresh Public Bath Bucket Shop Nature*     10％     6％  210G+Nature 
    Cart    Stew Cart   Merchant C. Nature*     10％     5％  160G+Nature
   Medicine School      Medicine S. Nature*     15％     10％ 420G+Nature
    Jizo    Jizo Statue Straw Hat   Nature*     10％     10％ 340G+Nature 
    Rice    Rice Shop   Bun Shop    Nature*     5％      10％ 170G+Nature 
    Lucky   Kimono Shop Cat Statue  Nature*     10％     15％ 700G+Nature
   Mountain Dumpling S. Jizo Statue Nature*     8％      8％  320G+Nature
   Hangover Stew Cart   Pub         Nature*     10％     5％  230G+Nature
    Study   School      Library     Nature*     10％     10％ 450G+Nature
    Warrior Samurai Ho. 5-Rf Tower  Nature*     10％     5％  2600G+Nature
    Hairpin General St. Kimono Shop Nature*     10％     12％ 400G+Nature
    Archive Jizo Statue Library     Nature*     15％     5％  410G+Nature 
    Beauty  Public Bath Bucket Shop General St. 15％     10％     310G    
    Sunny   Park        Jizo Statue Fire Alarm  12％     10％     470G    
   Shipping General St. Greengrocer Medicine Sh 12％     10％     300G    
    Fried   Tempura Sh. Bun Shop    Udon Shop   12％     10％     270G    
    Fiery   Fire Stati. Fire Alarm  Well        25％     -        880G   
    Fun     Zoo         Kabuki The. 5-Rf Tower  20％     5％      3400G   
    Scholar School      Samurai Ho. Library     25％     5％      1650G   
   Literary Library     Library     Ukiyoe Shop 15％     10％     900G    
   Training Weapon Shop Dojo        Notice Boa. 20％     10％     1080G   
    Edomae  Sushi Shop  Fireworks   Tempura Sh. 20％     12％     550G    
    Steamy  Pine Tree   Hot Spring  Boulder     25％     10％     1930G   
    Import  Elekiter    Camera Shop Zoo         25％     25％     2800G   
    Fortune Cat Statue  Case Shop   Shrine      25％     10％     1300G   
    Komon   Case Shop   Sandal Shop Straw Hat   20％     -        680G   
    Kyoto   Samurai Ho. 5-Rf Tower  Kimono Shop 20％     15％     2950G   
    Gambler Gambling S. Pawn Shop   Pub         5％      25％     550G    
    Corrupt Magistrate  Fancy Rest. Bun Shop    10％     10％     2050G   
    Ghost   Well        Willow Tree Wooden Path 15％      -       295G   
    Healthy Greengrocer Merchant C. Medicine S. 15％     10％     280G    
   Traveler Sandal Shop Straw Hat   Carriage S. 25％     15％     680G    
    Battle  Turret      Cannon      Weapon Sh.  30％     10％     850G**
    Playboy Gambling S. Kimono Shop Kabuki The. 20％     20％     1400G   
    Vehicle Stables     Handcart S. Carriage S. 20％     25％     1700G   
    Clothes Kimono Shop Large Store Fancy Rest. 16％     15％     1550G   
   Princess Carriage S. Kimono Sho  Fancy Rest. 21％     15％     1850G   
    Samurai Magistrate  Castle      Samurai Ho. 25％     15％     5200G***
    Karosft Kairo Statu Banana Tree Scarecrow   35％     35％     4476G

*Like trees, boulders, the fire alarm, or scarecrow.
**Most cost-effective combo for high yield!
***Most expensive combo for its yield.
```

If you're looking for tips on combo stacking/chaining, check out http://kairospot.net/community/threads/10x-combo-on-castle.1414/ (The thread is entitled 10x Combo On Castle.)

Comment: Would you mind adding the list of combos to your answer? The link is great but if it goes dead for whatever reason, having te list here would be helpful.

Comment: @AshleyNunn - I've added the table to the answer, although I had to  do some rather ugly formatting to make it fit halfway nicely.